# Is there a work around way to compile MFC files in Microsoft Visual C++

Tags: mfc

Is there a work around way to compile MFC files in Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that Windows Driver Developer Kit contains MFC 4.2 headers and libraries. I newer tested if this is enough to compile even simple MFC application using Express Edition of VS, but I guess this is your only chance.

Comment: What doesn't work? Can't it find required headers and libraries or something else? Have you set directories in VS correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can find an old copy of the visual studio environment?

Comment: I need to find MFC 4.2 headers, but the questions is where, to look for them.